# Block an IP address from apache2

Tags: apache2

Can I block certain IPs from accessing my apache completely (not only a certain virtualhost)?

I want to do this on my VPS and I don't want to use iptables.

I'd like to configure my apache2 so that it doesn't allow certain IPs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: ServerFault would have a better audience for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go this should be what you are looking for. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_access.html

Comment: that good but not enough , he don't want to limit it at the virtualhost only i believe.